# EF6 is using the wrong key when eager loading

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have successfully set up EF6 on Chinook database using SqlLite .NET provider.

Now, Playlists and Tracks is a many-many relationship mapped through the junction table PlaylistTracks.

The following query generates the wrong SQL statement where Track is mapped to PlaylistId (It should be TrackId) on the junction table.

```
var result = context.Playlists
                    .Where(p => p.Name == "Brazilian Music")
                    .SelectMany(pt => pt.PlaylistTracks)
                    .Include(pt => pt.Track).OrderBy(pt => pt.TrackId);
```

SQL trace:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[PlaylistId] AS [PlaylistId], 
[Extent2].[PlaylistId] AS [PlaylistId1], 
[Extent2].[TrackId] AS [TrackId], 
[Extent3].[TrackId] AS [TrackId1], 
[Extent3].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent3].[AlbumId] AS [AlbumId], 
[Extent3].[MediaTypeId] AS [MediaTypeId], 
[Extent3].[GenreId] AS [GenreId], 
[Extent3].[Composer] AS [Composer], 
[Extent3].[Milliseconds] AS [Milliseconds], 
[Extent3].[Bytes] AS [Bytes], 
[Extent3].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice]
FROM   [Playlist] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [PlaylistTrack] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PlaylistId] = [Extent2].[PlaylistId]
INNER JOIN [Track] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[PlaylistId] = [Extent3].[TrackId]
WHERE 'Brazilian Music' = [Extent1].[Name]
ORDER BY [Extent2].[TrackId] ASC
```

Somewhere towards the end of the last INNER JOIN I get

**[Extent2].[PlaylistId] = [Extent3].[TrackId]**

It should be [Extent2].[TrackId] = [Extent3].[TrackId] where [Extent2] is the junction table.

How can I make EF6 map to the correct foreign key?

Appreciate any help.

See my original question
[Linq query returns the same names even though they should be different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100436/linq-query-returns-the-same-names-even-though-they-should-be-different)

Here is how I configured the POCOs

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Name} (PlaylistId = {PlaylistId})")]
public class Playlist
{
    [Key]
    public int PlaylistId { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(120)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TrackId")]
    public virtual ICollection<PlaylistTrack> PlaylistTracks { get; set; }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("{Name} (TrackId = {TrackId})")]
public class Track
{
    [Key]
    public int TrackId { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? AlbumId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int MediaTypeId { get; set; }

    public int? GenreId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(220)]
    public string Composer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Milliseconds { get; set; }

    public int Bytes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AlbumId")]
    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GenreId")]
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MediaTypeId")]
    public virtual MediaType MediaType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("InvoiceLineId")]
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceLine> InvoiceLines { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PlaylistId")]
    public virtual ICollection<PlaylistTrack> PlaylistTracks { get; set; }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("PlaylistId = {PlaylistId}, TrackId = {TrackId}")]
public class PlaylistTrack
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PlaylistId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int TrackId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PlaylistId")]
    public virtual Playlist Playlist { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TrackId")]
    public virtual Track Track { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You should show your entities config code

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it fixed. I messed up the relationship mappings.

Track and Playlist should be as follows:

```
public class Track
{
  ...
  [ForeignKey("TrackId")]
  public virtual ICollection<PlaylistTrack> PlaylistTracks { get; set; }
}

public class Playlist
{
  ...
  [ForeignKey("PlaylistId")]
  public virtual ICollection<PlaylistTrack> PlaylistTracks { get; set; }
}
```

Cheers